# Remove Break in Kotlin When Expression

Tags: java, switch-statement, kotlin

How can I write **When Expression** in kotlin without break the expression? In Java we can do like this.

```
int x = 3;
switch (x){
   case 1:
      System.out.println("1");
   case 2:
      System.out.println("2");  
   case 3:
      System.out.println("3");  // 3 will be printed
   case 4:
      System.out.println("4");  // 4 will be printed
}
```

**Result:

3

4**

How can I achieve result like this?

Answer (score 6):

Currently it's not possible to implement the fall through structure of **Java** `switch` statement using **Kotlin** `when`.

**Workaround:**

```
val x = 3

if (x <= 1) println("1")
if (x <= 2) println("2")
if (x <= 3) println("3")
if (x <= 4) println("4")
```

*[@yole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole):*

> We have a tentative plan to support the continue keyword in when
>   statements to support fallthrough. It's not scheduled for any specific
>   future version of Kotlin, though.